# Pattern matching a domain name

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I don't use pattern matching as often as I should.
I am matching a domain name for the following:

```
1. If it starts with www., then remove that portion and return.
   www.stackoverflow.com => "stackoverflow.com"
2. If it has either example.com or example.org, strip that out and return.
   blog.example.com => "blog"
3. return request.domain
   hello.world.com => "hello.world.com"

def filterDomain(request: RequestHeader): String = {
  request.domain match {
    case //?? case #1 => ?
    case //?? case #2 => ?
    case _ => request.domain
  }
}
```

How do I reference the value (request.domain) inside the expression and see if it starts with "www." like:

```
if request.domain.startsWith("www.") request.domain.substring(4)
```

Comment: 1. Are you against a recursive method?  2. What should happen to `www.blog.example.com`?

Comment: @childofsoong I don't need to support that case, just 1 level of subdomains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the variable you pattern matching a name and Scala will infer its type, plus you can put an if statement in you case expression as follows

```
def filterDomain(request: RequestHeader): String = {
request.domain match {
  case domain if domain.startsWith("www.") => domain.drop(4)
  case domain if domain.contains("example.org") | domain.contains("example.com") => domain.takeWhile(_!='.')
  case _ => request.domain
 }
}
```

Note that the order of the case expressions matters.

Comment: He doesn't care that it starts with 'blog', he cares that it ends in 'example.com' or 'example.org'

Comment: Or, rather, that it contains them (presumably at the end)

Comment: Well, it's still a bit off - if it's `thing.example.com` he wants `thing`, not `blog`

Comment: Nice use of takewhile, didn't think of that.  i was using both substring and indexOf.

Comment: The way he worded it, "thing.example.com.somethingelse" should return "thing.somthingelse", but I doubt he really means that, so this is probably fine.

Comment: @childofsoong its fine, and its in production now :)

Answer (score 1):

When writing `case` clauses you can do something like:

```
case someVar if someVar.length < 2 => someVar.toLowerCase
```

This should make pretty clear how grabbing matched values works.
So in this case, you would need to write something like:

```
case d if d.startsWith("www.") => d.substring(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead set on using a regex rather than `String` methods such as `startsWith` and `contains`, you can do the following:

```
val wwwMatch = "(?:www\\.)(.*)".r
val exampleMatch = "(.*)(?:\\.example\\.(?:(?:com)|(?:org)))(.*)".r
def filterDomain(request: String): String = {
  request.domain match {
    case wwwMatch(d) => d
    case exampleMatch(d1, d2) => d1 + d2
    case _ => request.domain
  }
}
```

Now, for maintainability's sake, I wouldn't go this way, because a month later, I will look at this and not remember what it's doing, but that's your call.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need pattern matching for that:

```
request.domain
  .stripPrefix("www.")
  .stripSuffix(".example.org")
  .stripSuffix(".example.com")
```